# Сервис временных эмейлов

Tags: email, postfix, веб-служба, dovecot

Есть желание в образовательных целях сделать сервис временных эмейлов по типу *temp-mail.ru, 10minutemail.com*... В гугле хватает рецептов по тому, как настроить postfix+dovecot с авторизацией пользователей по логину и паролю и прочим лишним функционалом, но нигде толком не объясняется как это работает.
Я хотел бы сохранять полученные письма в mysql (чтобы потом мой backend сайта мог отдавать письма клиенту по запросу) - это можно сделать при помощи postfix filter, но я не понимаю как мне завести виртуальные домены, генерировать пользователей (которым не требуется авторизация) и, собственно, как получать почту имея статический ip и, в перспективе, домен, а пока *xip.io*
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда мне смотреть и что мне нужно для реализации описанного.

Answer (score 1):

1. Я бы не стал называть авторизацию пользователей по логину и паролю лишним функционалом. Если с вашего сервиса пользователь может прочитать почту, полученную на такой временный адрес e-mail, то пользователя надо авторизовать. И для возможности отправки почты через сервис авторизация тоже нужна, без неё сервис начнут использовать спамеры.
2. Для получения почты на какой-то домен для него в DNS надо создать MX запись, указывающую на имя хоста вашего сервера (который в свою очередь, я имеет в DNS запись типа A, указывающую на ваш статический IP). Если вы хотите динамически управлять именами в контролируемых вами зонах DNS, то в дополнение к почтовым полезно будет обзавестись и собственным DNS сервером, и научиться им управлять.
3. Для вашего проекта на почтовом севере не нужно создавать многочисленные домены. Вместо этого можно обойтись некоторой схемой маршрутизации разнообразных сочетаний имён аккаунтов и доменов в пространство имён одного домена, например, tmpuser@virtdomain -> tmpuser-virtdomain@one.real.dom. В принципе, можно обойтись и единственным аккаунтом, куда складывать такую почту, полученную для виртуальных адресов, добавляя заголовок с оригинальным адресом получателя.
4. Это стоило бы указать первым пунктом: судя по уровню вопросов, вы мало знакомы с тем, как работают почтовые системы в более-менее стандартных конфигурациях. Дабы не наломать дров в дизайне собственной системы, рекомендую развернуть какую-нибудь готовую систему с базовыми почтовыми функциями и попрактиковаться на ней. Рекомендую попробовать [CommuniGate Pro](http://www.communigate.com/CommuniGatePro/): просто устанавливается (можно вообще запускать из командной строки), имеет простой API для интеграции с внешними скриптами обработки почты, бесплатен для пяти (семи, если считать служебные) аккаунтов.

Comment: По пункту 1. Весь смысл подобных сервисов - отсутствие регистрации. Отправка писем там как правило отсутствует, а сам адрес "живет" несколько минут.

Comment: Если письмо надо уметь прочитать только в рамках той же сессии, в которой был создан временный адрес, то можно обойтись и без средств аутентификации. Согласен.

Comment: Обычно так оно и выглядит